# SPARQL - Filter all instances that only contain a condition

Tags: filter, sparql, rdf

I have recipes with ingredients that have a category.

```
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix ex:     <http://example.org> .

ex:recipe1  a                    schema:Recipe ;
        schema:recipeIngredient  ex:ingredient1 , ex:ingredient3 .
ex:recipe2  a                    schema:Recipe ;
        schema:recipeIngredient  ex:ingredient1, ex:ingredient2 .

ex:ingredient1  ex:category  ex:plant .
ex:ingredient2  ex:category  ex:spice .
ex:ingredient3  ex:category  ex:meat .
ex:ingredient4  ex:category  ex:fish .
```

I want to filter all recipes that *only* contain ingredients from the category `ex:plants` or `ex:spice`. I tried:

```
SELECT ?recipes 
WHERE {
   ?recipes     a                       schema:Recipe; 
                schema:recipeIngredient ?ingredient.
    ?ingredient ex:category             ?category.                
    FILTER(?category NOT IN (ex:meat && ex:fish)) 
  }
```

This returns both recipes, I guess because `ex:recipe1` also includes a `ex:plant`. However, my desired output is only `ex:recipe2` because it does not contain any `ex:meat` or `ex:fish`. If any `ex:meat` or `ex:fish` is included in the recipes, I want it to be excluded from the result set.

Comment: `FILTER NOT EXISTS` is the way to go, because what SPARQL will do is to find at least one binding that won't conflict the condition.

Comment: what does `(ex:meat && ex:fish)` by the way? I thought a list is denoted by a comma

Comment: `SELECT ?recipes 
WHERE {
   ?recipes     a                       schema:Recipe; 
                
   FILTER NOT EXISTS {
     ?recipes schema:recipeIngredient ?ingredient.   
     ?ingredient ex:category             ?category.  
      FILTER(?category IN (ex:meat, ex:fish)) 
   }
                  
   
  }`

Comment: thank you! that is working! do you want to make an answer out of it?